# Animation time offset for multiple objects

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

Trying to rotate objects by setting copy location from already rotating empty, and driver, as a influence controller for every object. 
I have 10 objects, but i'd like to set an offset, so every object will rotate few frames after previous one. 
How should I achive this result?

I have Animation Nodes, so I can try this way, but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a delay with the "Delay Time" node in Animation Nodes and then restraining the animation with a "Math" node set to "Maximum" :

[image]

Result :

[image]