# Movie as image texture on multiple objects, with different frame offset, without using multiple materials?

Tags: animation, texturing, image, video

I want to model a couple of screens that use a movie as image texture. The difficult part here for me is to have different screens show parts of the same source material starting with different frames. So e.g. screen 1 should start with an `Offset` parameter of 0, screen 2 with 300, and other values. (Random values might be okay or even be desirable.)

How to do this in Blender? The only way I was able to manipulate the `Offset` parameter was via a Driver, but from what I understand that only allows a global, object independent manipulation anyway. Help?  Below is a list of things I have considered and tried in vain. Thanks!

### Visuals

Here is a generic screenshot of an image node to show what I referred to with `Offset` parameter.

[image: Pretty generic screenshot of a image texture node. The "Offset" parameter is having a purple background, since a Driver was set for it.]

### Related answers

> [Can I use an image sequence with offset frames as a texture on array items](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1911/can-i-use-an-image-sequence-with-offset-frames-as-a-texture-on-array-items)

Uses a lot of different materials and I see this option. But that would require me to have many dozens of materials and setting the offset parameter on each of them manually. Does not seem like a good solution to me.

> [How to change a material texture per object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178583/how-to-change-a-material-texture-per-object)

Uses a script to clone objects and materials. Seems like the best workaround at the moment, though still labourious and not really elegant.

> [Animation time offset for multiple objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173947/animation-time-offset-for-multiple-objects)

Uses Animation Nodes to delay regular animation. I couldn't find a way to change the video offset with Animation Nodes.

### Update

The question was marked as a duplicate. After thinking about it more, my question could have better been put as: **How to do what I want to do without using multiple materials?** From this I read here and in other answers I take it that there is no better way to achieve the results I desire without having multiple materials. This is somewhat unsatisfactory, but probably can't be helped.

Comment: @susu Thanks! Technically it answers the question, however it is similar or equal to the approach used in the first "related answer". I intend to create quite a few objects playing that video and I was hoping to get around creating that many separate materials.

Comment: Thank you @susu for kindly updating the question!